# Не происходит сложение alert выводит NaN

Tags: javascript

```js
"use strict";
var n = 89;
digital_root(n);

function digital_root(n) {
  n = String(n);
  var sum;
  var m;

  for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {

    m = +n[i];
    sum = sum + m;
    sum += m;
    console.log(sum);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли инициализировать переменную sum.

```js
"use strict";
var n=89;
digital_root(n);
function digital_root(n) {
    n = String(n);
    var sum = 0;
    var m = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i<n.length; i++){  

        m = +n[i];
        sum = sum + m;
        sum += m;
        alert(sum);
    }
  }
```

А теперь почему так.

NaN (Not a Number) это ошибка арифметической операции (взято с [euSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14977803/7663131)). Собственно любая математика, когда хотя бы один из операндов у нас undefined или NaN вернет нам NaN.

```
1 + undefined           // NaN
"1" + undefined         // "1undefined"
1 + "" + undefined      // "1undefined"
1 + ("" + undefined)    // "1undefined"
typeof NaN              // "number"
typeof undefined        // "undefined"
NaN === NaN             // false (it's not reflexive!)
undefined === undefined // true (it's reflexive)
NaN.toString()          // "NaN"
```

Чтобы понять NaN это или нет также не достаточно использовать операторы сравнения.

```
NaN === NaN;        // false
Number.NaN === NaN; // false
isNaN(NaN);         // true
isNaN(Number.NaN);  // true
```